# Why does adding 20 elements cause allocation, but adding 19 does not

Tags: memory, julia, variadic-functions

I noted that an `@generated` function I was working with would sometimes allocate and sometimes not depending on one of the parameters.

I have narrowed it down to this simple case.
The cut off for allocation free addition seems to come down to adding 20 or more elements.

19 is fine 20 is not.
adding 10 twice is also fine.

See the code;

```
function add19(x)
    @inbounds ret = x[1]+ x[2]+ x[3]+ x[4]+ x[5]+ x[6]+ x[7]+ x[8]+ x[9]+ x[10]+ x[11]+ x[12]+ x[13]+ x[14]+ x[15]+ x[16]+ x[17]+ x[18]+ x[19]
    ret
end

function add20(x)
    @inbounds ret = x[1]+ x[2]+ x[3]+ x[4]+ x[5]+ x[6]+ x[7]+ x[8]+ x[9]+ x[10]+ x[11]+ x[12]+ x[13]+ x[14]+ x[15]+ x[16]+ x[17]+ x[18]+ x[19]+ x[20]
    ret
end


function add10twice(x)
    @inbounds ret = (x[1]+ x[2]+ x[3]+ x[4]+ x[5]+ x[6]+ x[7]+ x[8]+ x[9]+ x[10]) + ( x[11]+ x[12]+ x[13]+ x[14]+ x[15]+ x[16]+ x[17]+ x[18]+ x[19]+ x[20])
    ret
end
```

timings/allocations (for `a = rand(Int8, 100)`

- `@btime add19($a)`   52.542 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
- `@btime add20($a)`   789.929 ns (20 allocations: 336 bytes)
- `@btime add10twice($a)`  80.959 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

So what is going on here?

(I have a theory it related to how varargs are handled)

Comment: Yes, vararg or splatting problem. Related: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/22255 . It may not be a problem in v0.7 because of https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/23912 . Not sure this is a good SO problem though.

Comment: Hmm I never thought it might be a bug. Just limitation on the number of args. Like that one were never allowed anything with an AST that was  a `:call` expression with more than 20 args (including function name), without allocating. Or that 19+ args resolved not into the function but into a `reduce(+,collect(args))`

Comment: It's running into hardcoded constants in the inference algorithm like https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/inference.jl#L38 . I'd call it a bug because better strategies like github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/23912 can workaround it, just not every possibility is implemented yet. The fact there are some inference limits is just a thing about the current state of Julia which can easily change (and some will change with v0.7, so you should double check this example).